# Front-End Editor email notification issue

Tags: front-end

I'm trying to send a notification email when a user updates a page/post, either in the backend or by using the [Front-End Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/).

It works fine when updating in the backend but no data is emailed through when updating with the Front-End Editor. Anybody have any ideas on this please?

```
function __test_on_publish( $post )
{   
global $post;
if( ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) || $post->post_status == 'auto-draft' )
return;

if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post ) )  {
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post ); 
    $post_url = get_permalink( $post ); 
    $aid = $post->post_author;
    $user_email = get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $aid);       
    $subject = 'A page has been updated'; 
    $message = "A page has been updated on " . get_bloginfo( 'name' ). " by ".$user_email."\n\n"; 
    $message .= $post_title. "\n\nView it: " . get_permalink( $post ) . "\n\nEdit it: " . get_edit_post_link( $post ). "\n\n"; 
    //send email to admin 

    wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), $subject, $message ); 

} 

}
add_action( 'pre_post_update', '__test_on_publish', 10, 3 );
```

**Edit:** I ended up adding some wp_mail functionality directly into the post.php file of Front-end Editor which seems to work well, (see below).

```
    function save( $data, $content ) {  

    /--- some original code omitted ---/

    wp_update_post( (object) $postdata );

    //// added ////
    $post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );        
    $post_tmp = get_post( $post_id );
    $aid = $post_tmp->post_author;
    $user_email = get_the_author_meta('user_nicename', $aid);           
    $subject = 'A page has been updated by '.$user_email; 
    $message = "A page has been updated on " . get_bloginfo( 'name' ). " by ".$user_email."\n\n"; 
    $message .= $post_title. "\n\nView it: " . get_permalink( $post_id ) . "\n\nEdit it: " . get_edit_post_link( $post_id ). "\n\n"; 
    wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), $subject, $message ); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Front End Editor calls `wp_update_post`, which in turn calls [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post). You should be able to hook either `save_post` or `wp_insert_post` for new/updated posts, and `edit_post` or `post_updated` for updated posts.

Comment: Thanks @Milo! They all work ok when updating using FEE, sending the email, but no data is being passed through : (

Comment: [have a look at the actions in source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post.php#L2692), the format of the arguments may differ between actions

Comment: Thanks @Milo. Ended up adding code directly to the plugin - see above.