# Email notification for editors only

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I would like to send an email to all editors of my blog when a new article has been published. I found many plugins but I want to solve this problem without plugins. In addition, I found a tutorial to send an email, but this is only for administrators of the blog but not for editors ([Front-End Editor email notification issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74952/front-end-editor-email-notification-issue)). I would be happy if you could give me a tip or advice. Thank you.

```
<?php

function notifyauthor( $post_id ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    $author = get_userdata( $post->post_author ); // How can I specify the role of the editors here?
    $subject = "Post Published: " . $post->post_title;
    $message = ' Hi ' . $author->display_name . ',
    Your post, "' . $post->post_title . '" has just been published.
    View post: ' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . 'Thanks';

    wp_mail( $role->user_email, $subject, $message );
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'notifyauthor' );
```

Comment: So you want to find a list of users by role so that you can loop through them and email them all? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/219686/3276

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes exactly. All editors should receive an email when an amount has been published. Admins are excluded. 
Do you know how I can build the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_users()` function. **[Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)**

```
function notify_editors( $post_id ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    // Get all editors
    $editors = get_users( [ 'role__in' => [ 'editor'] ] );

    foreach ( $editors as $editor ) {

        // Setup email
        $subject = "Post Published: " . $post->post_title;
        $message = ' Hi ' . $editor->display_name . ',
        Your post, "' . $post->post_title . '" has just been published.
        View post: ' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . 'Thanks';

        // and send...
        wp_mail( $editor->user_email, $subject, $message );
     }
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'notify_editors' );
```

You can read more [**here**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/), about optional `headers` parameter that can add fields like `from`, `cc`, `content-type` etc.

Comment: That's excellent. Thank you very much.